# Intersect in linq to return different property

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have a query on linq:

```
public void method()              
{
var answers = Answers.GetAnswers;

var oneA = (from a in answers
                    where a.Questionid == "Q101b" && a.AnswerValue.Length > 0
                    select new QuestionInfo { userId = a.UserId, questionId = a.Questionid }).ToList();

        var mumsHabits = oneA.Intersect(mothers, new UserIdEqualityComparer()).ToList();
```

}

in my method, I am trying to get a list of all mumsHabits with answerValue but I only get userid's and questionid.

Thanks

mothers is defined as List mothers;

answers contain 'answer' which is defined as:

```
public partial class Answer : INotifyPropertyChanging, INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    private static PropertyChangingEventArgs emptyChangingEventArgs = new PropertyChangingEventArgs(String.Empty);

    private int _AnswerId;

    private string _Questionid;

    private int _UserId;

    private string _AnswerValue;

    private string _SelectionValue;

    private System.DateTime _DateAnswered;

    private string _Question;

    private EntityRef<User> _User;

}
```

Comment: This is because `oneA` has only `UserId` and `questionId`

Comment: try with `var mumsHabits = mothers.Intersect(oneA , new UserIdEqualityComparer()).ToList();`

Answer (score 0):

You can get all the fields by selecting all the elements into `oneA` Like this

```
var oneA = (from a in answers
                where a.Questionid == "Q101b" && a.AnswerValue.Length > 0
                select a).ToList();

var mumsHabits = oneA.Intersect(mothers, new UserIdEqualityComparer()).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
var IDList = answers.Where(a => a.Questionid == "Q101b" && a.AnswerValue.Length > 0).Select(a => a.UserId).ToList();
var mumsHabits = mothers.Where(m => IDList.Contains(m._UserId)).ToList();
```

The first one gets all UserId's where the Answer ID is Q101b and there is something in the AnswerValue field.

The next picks all mothers that have an ID in the IDList.